# Parametric curve area

Tags: calculus

I was reading about heart shaped curves on mathworld.wolfram and happened to see this https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html

I saw that they represented the heart shaped curve as an parametric equation

[image]

And the areas [image]

So I was wondering how they got the areas of these? and what do they mean by $A_1$ etc??

""update""

Forget about the $A_1$ part, it was just the area of the different graphs. But how did they calculate $A_5$ or any of the areas?

Comment: Stop posting unsearchable pictures and instead typeset (using *MathJax*).

Comment: unsearchable? what do you mean

Comment: "Unsearchable" means that when someone is looking for a term or even a value (e.g., $3.661971715$) that is in your picture, they will not find it.  Likewise, the automatic search when someone is posting a new question will not find material in such a picture.  By the way, please read this:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: If you had read the article a little more carefully, you would understand that $A_i$ refer to the six curves given at the start of the article.

Comment: @BernardMassé I realized that, that's why I added an ""update""

Answer (score 2):

Let a closed simple curve be given parametrically as $x(t),y(t)$, where $a$ is the least positive value of the parameter such that $x(a)=x(0)$, $y(a)=y(0)$. Then the area enclosed by the curve is
$$
A=\left|\int_0^a x(t)y'(t) dt\right|.
$$

Comment: I tried using that, but I only got $A=168\pi$ and not $A=180\pi$

Comment: @UnderGrad1993 I tried as well and obtained $180\pi$.

Comment: I got $180\pi$ as well now, thanks a lot.